# Eclipse IDE yellow warning icon on main activity

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Apologies for not fully explaining the problem within my original question.

Below you can see an image of the source code where the warnings are occurring. I am new to this, and am therefore unaware of how to solve this.

[Source code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6miqA.jpg)

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: What is so bad about the warning? What does the warning say? We are no psychic here you know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just means there are warnings about issues in that source file. Edit the file to see the warnings or look in the 'Problems' view.

The warning icon will be removed once you fix the warnings in your code.